# CSS animation rendering inconsistently on iOS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to make a `div` repeatedly appear instantly and slowly fade-out, at arbitrary intervals.

JS used to make the `div` appear:

```js
div.classList.remove('fade-out');
div.offsetWidth;
div.classList.add('fade-out');
```

With this CSS:

```css
.fade-out {
    animation: fadeOut 2.5s ease-out;
}

@keyframes fadeOut { from { opacity: 1; } to { opacity: 0; } }

div { opacity: 0; }
```

For some reason, this works as expected in desktop Chrome, Safari & Firefox, but on iOS around half of the time the animation isn't played — the div just disappears after 2.5 seconds with no progressive opacity change. This happens both on both iPhone and iPad, with both Firefox and Safari.

###### Stuff tried since the initial post:

- Add `animation: none` to the element's original definition.
- Set the `animation` property through JS instead.
- Use `100%` and `0%` instead of `to` and `from`.
- Setting the `div`'s initial opacity to 1 instead of 0 and add `animation-fill-mode: forward`.
- Add a short delay with `setTimeOut`.
- Use full animation definition instead of shorthand notation.
- Additional definition using `-webkit-animation` and `@-webkit-keyframes`.

Using any of the above doesn't have an effect on the animation, which still works as expected everyhere except on iOS.

###### (Not a real) solution

The only way I could make iOS display the animation consistently was by adding a short delay to the animation:

`animation: fadeOut 2.5s ease-out 0.01s`

However, since the `div`'s "instant display then fade-out" animation can be triggered while an old animation is still running on it, the delay adds a noticeable one-frame flash which is undesirable (regardless of how low I set the delay value).

Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe adding a setInterval to the js will help

Comment: I suppose you mean `setTimeout`. I tried that, adding a short delay before add the `.fade-out` class. This doesn't change the inconsistent behavior on iOS, and it also creates a visible flash when the class is added (since the fade out animation has already started).

Comment: yes that is what i meant